# Wordpress - get only primary post category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display only the primary category of the posts, but not the first. I don't use a plugin for the primary category.

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: @AkshayShah I can't figure out how to display only the primary category.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This isn't a coding service. Before posting a question, it is expected that you have ***researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself***. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can help you with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can able to display a specific category posts by using WP_Query object.Display posts that have this category (and any children of that category), using category slug: Put this code where you want to display posts from "primary" category.

```
<?php
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => 'primary',
    'order'=>'ASC');

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="smal-sec">
            <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
            <?php the_content();?>
        </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

I think this could help you. For more reference visit : [Codex WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)